# What does "Place under the common denominator" mean?

Tags: factoring, fractions

The Step "Place under the common denominator", the $-1$ turned into $-e$, but it originally was $-r$. I understand with factoring out the $r$, it becomes $-1$, but how did it become a $-e$?

Can you please specifically answer to the question and not in an abstract manner?

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle\frac{E}{e}=\frac{R+r}{r}&\\
\displaystyle\frac{E}{e}\times r=\frac{R+r}{r}\times r&\text{multiply both sides by $r$}\\
\displaystyle\frac{r\;E}{e}=R+r&\text{simplify}\\
\displaystyle\frac{r\;E}{e}-r=R&\text{substract $r$ from both sides}\\
\displaystyle r\left(\frac{E}{e}-1\right)=R&\text{factor out $r$}\\
\displaystyle\color{red}{r\left(\frac{E-e}{e}\right)=R}&\color{red}{\text{place under common denominator}}\\
\displaystyle r\left(\frac{E-e}{e}\right)\times\frac{e}{E-e}=R\times\frac{e}{E-e}&\text{multiply both sides by $\displaystyle\frac{e}{E-e}$}\\
\displaystyle r=\frac{eR}{E-e}
\end{array}
$$

[(Image that replaced text).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD4GH.png)

Comment: It should be "place *over* a common denominator," not *under*. In other words, combine terms by having the same denominator.

Comment: Thanks Ted. That makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ r\left(\frac{E}{e} -1 \right) = R$$
$$ r\left(\frac{E}{e} -1\times \frac{e}{e} \right) = r\left(\frac{E - e}{e} \right)$$

You can multiply anything by $1$ and $e$ divided by $e$ is $1$.  Once you have two fractions with the same denominator, you can make the denominator common:

$$\frac{a}{b} - \frac{c}{b} = \frac{a-c}{b}$$

Comment: Why do we add the extra (x e/e)?

Comment: I edited the answer to explain why you can add the extra multiplication.  Why you do it is another matter.  It's usually because you like the way the equation looks after the following step.

Comment: Oooohh I get it now! 28/28 is 1 just like e/e is 1. You would do it, because all the terms are in abstract letters. Thank you so much

Comment: Sorry, just to check, does this mean that r = eR/E - 1 could also be correct?

Comment: It doesn't look correct at first glance.  What steps did you use to get there?

Comment: Well, at the red step the equation is r(E - 1/ e). Without changing the 1 to an e, if I multiplied the denominator e, and applied it to the other side, changing it to r(E - 1) = eR. Then the next step I would divide (E - 1) on the left and apply to the right, making it r = eR/E-1

Comment: $r(E - 1/e)\times e = R \times e$ is what you get by multiplying both sides by e.  That becomes $r(Ee - 1) = eR$.  The (entire) LHS must be multiplied by $e$ if you are multiplying the RHS by $e$.  In general, $(a-b)\times c = ac - bc$. That is why I have an $Ee$ in my expression after multiplying both sides by $e$, which is the way to change the $1$ into an $e$.  What you did, on the hand, is not correct.